# alternative to kivy filechooser

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Is there a way to make kivy's built in filechooser be able to choose directories as well as files?

I had looked at kivy garden's filebrowser, but wanted to know if there was a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there is a really easy solution.

I'm using .kv files so for me the solution is

```
 FileChooserIconView:
      ...
      dirselect: True #This is just disabled by default
```